# Merge partitions

Tags: linux, zfs

Due to some unfortunate partitioning I ended up with the following layout:

```
/dev/sda1  (0-120MB)      128MB  (boot)
/dev/sda2  (128MB-500GB)  500GB  (empty)
/dev/sda3  (500GB-1TB)    500GB  (zfs)
/dev/sda4  (1TB-1.1TB)    100GB  (ext4)
/dev/sda5  (1.1TB-end)    100GB  (zfs)
```

I created a ZFS pool on `sda5`, moved the files previously residing on `sda3` there, added `sda3` to the pool and moved the files from `sda2` there. I intend to add `sda2` as well, move the stuff from `sda4` (my current root) and use ZFS as the root.

However, the root ZFS may not consist of multiple vdevs, and once the whole disk can be used by ZFS, it would be more reasonable to just merge the partitions into this layout:

```
/dev/sda1  (0-128MB)    128MB   (boot)
/dev/sda6  (128MB-end)  1200GB  (zfs)
```

I have free space at the start in `sda2`, I could create a new pool, move everything there and then just edit the `sda2` partition to reach to the end of the disk.

But does ZFS maybe support this without moving around everything again? Could I just replace my existing partitions with the `sda6` one and coax ZFS into finding the root blocks it placed on `sda3` and `sda5`?